# Updating constraints on orientation change

Tags: swift, autolayout, orientation, adaptive-layout

Below is the view in portrait mode (Image 1) and in landscape I wanted to show as (Image 2). I am facing issue to show in it properly in landscape.

Image 1:
[image]

I have setup constraints in storyboard.

```
greenView: top: 0, leading: 0, trailing: 0, width: equal to superview.width, height: equal to superview.height/2
```

Image 2: [image]
I tried modifying constraints but when I turn device to landscape, greenView becomes 1/4 of the screen. below is the code.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.50).isActive = true
        greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI you need to call `super.viewWillTransition`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of headache of creating constraints for this problem insert both views in a `UIStackView` (vertical) , and inside `viewWillTransition` change axis to horizontal if the orientation is `isLandscape`

plus adding these constraints

```
greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.50).isActive = true
greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
```

will make a conflict as the old ones are not removed

//

```
func shared () {

     if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {

         self.stView.axis = .vertical
     }
     else {

         self.stView.axis = .horizontal 
     }

 }
```

Call the above method in `viewDidLoad` & `viewWillTransition`

Comment: let me check by adding UIStackView.

Comment: UIStackView is doing the trick, but when I rotate its splitting in half based on height and not based on width. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`isActive` flag is highly misunderstood option. This flag does not change constraint's state, it completely adds or removes a constraint.

```
greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.50).isActive = true
greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
```

The above code will add multiple constraint on your view. Every time you rotate your device a new width, height constraint gets added to your view which will result in your view having multiple height and width constraints. To add/remove same constraint, store its reference then use `isActive` on it.

I'm not sure why you are setting height constraint to 0?

Now coming to what you want to do. I can think of 2 approaches

## 1st Approach

Add two more constraints in addition to existing constraints in your storyboard but keep their priority low(<1000):

```
1. greenView.bottom = safeArea.bottom
2. greenView.width = superView.width/2
```

Make IBOutlet of `greenView.height = superview.height/2 and greenView.trailing = superView.trailing`. *The outlets should be of those constraints which have high priority*. **Make sure your Outlets are not weak otherwise their outlet will become nil when you set `isActive false`**. Now all you have to do is set this when device changes to landscape mode:

```
highPriorityGreenViewConstraint.isActive = false
highPriorityHeightConstraint.isActive = false
```

## 2nd Approach

Use size classes to set your constraint. All size classes are mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/).

Example - Install `greenView.bottom = safeArea.bottom`,`greenView.width = superView.width/2` constraints for `compact width compact height` size class only. You will have to put more constraints in this approach as landscape size class is different even among iPhone models.